# Accessing a variable in a void function to be used in other functions? C++

Tags: c++

Is it possible to access the `d_nr` variable outside of this function without returning it and how would I do that? I want to keep the return value void.

Not sure if this code is any help but this is the function in question. I wan't to access the `d_nr` variable outside of this function without returning it.

```
void read(data & P, string file_name)
{
    int d_nr = 0, i = 0;
    string line;
    ifstream D(file_name);
    while(getline(D, line))
    {
        istringstream iss (line); 
        iss >> P.string[d_nr];
        while(iss.good())
        {
            iss >> P.var_1[i][d_nr] >> P.var_2[i][d_nr];
            i++;
        }
        d_nr++;
        i = 0;
    }
    D.close();
}
```

Comment: If the function is a member of a class, can't the variable be another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it a parameter with reference call.

```
void read(data & P, string file_name, int &d_nr)
{
    d_nr = 0;
    ...
```

Comment: I believe this answer is better than my answer of having a global variable. Would +1 but ran out of my votes for the day.

Comment: I know but I don't want to do that because then I'd have to enter the parameter when calling the function. Right?

Comment: Why do you have those drastic restriction ?

Comment: I don't know. I'm awful at programming. I guess this would be the best way to do it. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a pointer to a extern variable

```
void read(data & P, string file_name, int *output)
```

and in the function update the output variable

```
*output = d_nr;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more parameter for the function. For example

```
void read(data & P, string file_name, int &d_nr )
{
    d_nr = 0;
//...
```

Or if data is some class then you can simply add one more data member to this class. For example

```
void read(data & P, string file_name )
{
    P.d_nr = 0;
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem that the function needs a specific signature, but you want additional information?

What, exactly, needs "access"?  What kind of threading/process expectations do we have?

A simple global variable could work if there's no multi-threading.  You could consider printing the value to stdout (this is probably a bad idea, but I have no idea what the context and requirements are, so it might be what you want.)  Or, another related idea that might be terrible but it's hard to say without more detail on what you're doing - you could write it to the file.

Can you be more detailed about what you are trying to do?  Probably a static variable would be best, assuming there's no threading issue.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can't access a variable declared within the **scope** of the function if you are not in that scope yourself.  Your two options to have access to that value outside of its scope is to either:

1. Copy its value to some other variable before leaving the scope (before the end of the function in this case).  Or...
2. Declare a variable with a larger scope and use that from within your function.

Ways to do this with the first method include returning the value, or copying the value to a global - like this:

```
int global_dnr = 0;
void read(data & P, string file_name) {
    int d_nr = 0, i = 0;
    // The rest of your code as is...
    global_dnr = d_nr;
}
```

Now you can access `global_dnr` anytime, and it should have the latest `d_nr` value.  If your `read` function were a class method, you could assign `d_nr` to a class variable as well.

For approach 2, you don't declare `d_nr` in your function at all - you can declare a global variable, pass a variable by reference as a parameter (though this is technically equivalent to returning the variable) or access a class member directly.  Here is an example using the global variable:

```
int d_nr = 0; // Here is the global declaration instead.
void read(data & P, string file_name) {
    d_nr = 0; // Set variable to 0, but don't declare it here.
    // The rest of your code as is...
}
```

These are your two options.  Only the implementation details vary.